# When using a JavaScript toolkit or framework, what a suggested accepted policy in consumption of MVC model data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

In a .Net MVC world, we have access to model data at the view level, and can easily make use of Razor syntax to iterate through lists, etc.  However, with the incorporation of a js framework like AngularJS, a shift in data access is considered:

1. Make all data request RESTful requests, and consume JSON data through Angular factories, etc.
2. Views are simply templates to present the data
3. Separate all JavaScript code into separate files (SOLID principles)

While in the AngularJS world I can see this working, I have recently run into an enterprise-level project where Knockout was brought into the mix a bit late in the MVC3 development process.

As such, the view had DTO/ViewModel data AND also contains Knockout data-bound controls, populated through RESTful requests, and JavaScript code is mixed into the Razor's *.cshtml code.

A new feature was required that presented data in a list.  I added a new data construct to the model data, thinking that this was the data transmitted in the response to the RESTful request.  Turns out it was not, but available on the MVC view as `@model` data. So on the view we now have a RESTful response, as well as MVC model (view model) data.

It didn't make sense to then JSON convert that data, then perform Knockout data binding, when I could simply use Razor syntax to do the same (round-about way of getting the same result).

This brings me to a related issue of using MVC model data in JS frameworks, and how to [keep proper separation of concerns](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/iLntJwik9nE) - not mixing your JS code in your view.

In moving forward, I don't like mixing the two methods of data access.

**Specifically:**
I would like to know if this is common practice - if so, because it was not properly planned out, or if there are other reasons to really mix the two.

Thanks.

Comment: You dont really want to mix the two, but when moving from one to the other there is obviously going to be a transition stage with enterprise level projects. You should really be going back and converting the old otherwise you wont get the full benefit... but getting sign off from the product owners can sometimes be a difficult sell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It didn't make sense to then JSON convert that data, then perform Knockout data binding, when I could simply use Razor syntax to do the same (round-about way of getting the same result).

That sentence stands out to me because if you can simply use Razor syntax to fulfill your project requirements, then why do you even need Knockout? Knockout, like Angular, provides rich functionality through two-way data-binding and can make a site interactive without having to do any page reloads. If you just need to display static (or rather, non-interactive data), then a Javascript data-binding framework isn't really necessary - especially when you can just strongly type it out in your Razor view.

In answer to your question, I don't think that it is common practice to mix the two methods of  data access - at least not on purpose. I feel the same way as you in that regard - I'd prefer only one method of data access and view rendering to reduce code clutter.